# Join two columns in Pandas, even both of them are null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataset with routing list:

```
| order | point | city | boxes | pallets |
|--| -- | -- | -- | -- |
| o12345 | 1 | X |b0|p0,p1|
|o12345|2|Y|-|p2,p3,p4|
|o12345|3|Z|b1|-|
|o34567|1|Q|-|-|
|o34567|2|W|b2,b3|p5,p6|
|o34567|3|E|-|p7|
|o34567|4|R|b4,b5|p8,p9,p10|
```

[image]

How to join the columns "boxes" and "pallets" to get "cargo" with list both of boxes and pallets inside and the to explode this column to get each value in separate row

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
df['cargo'] = df['pallets']+','+ df['boxes']
print(df)
```

But not works with null values:(

Firstly expect to get:
[image]

And then to explode only for cargo:
[image]

Comment: What is the logic required to define cargo column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```py
df['cargo'] = (df[['boxes', 'pallets']]
                .apply(lambda x: ','.join([i for i in x if i]), axis=1))
df = df.drop(['boxes', 'pallets'], axis=1)
print(df)

    order  point city            cargo
0  o12345      1    X         b0,p0,p1
1  o12345      2    Y         p2,p3,p4
2  o12345      3    Z               b1
3  o34567      1    Q                 
4  o34567      2    W      b2,b3,p5,p6
5  o34567      3    E               p7
6  o34567      4    R  b4,b5,p8,p9,p10


df['cargo'] = df['cargo'].str.split(',')
df = (df.explode('cargo').sort_values(by=['order', 'point']))
print(df)
```

---

```
    order  point city cargo
0  o12345      1    X    b0
0  o12345      1    X    p0
0  o12345      1    X    p1
1  o12345      2    Y    p2
1  o12345      2    Y    p3
1  o12345      2    Y    p4
2  o12345      3    Z    b1
3  o34567      1    Q      
4  o34567      2    W    b2
4  o34567      2    W    b3
4  o34567      2    W    p5
4  o34567      2    W    p6
5  o34567      3    E    p7
6  o34567      4    R    b4
6  o34567      4    R    b5
6  o34567      4    R    p8
6  o34567      4    R    p9
6  o34567      4    R   p10
```

Comment: when trying df['cargo'] = (df[['boxes', 'pallets']]
                .apply(lambda x: ','.join([i for i in x if i]), axis=1))
df = df.drop(['boxes', 'pallets'], axis=1)
print(df)                     --> getting this TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found